# Android: fragment over the app bar

Tags: android, layout, fragment, overlay

I have an app with `Navigation Drawer` and a fragment with `ScrollView` and `widgets`.

The problem is that the fragment widgets are appear over the app bar. Is it possible to adjust the fragment layout so it starts under the app bar?

Thank you in advance!

Screenshot:
[image]

**This is my fragment xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="it.bitrack.fabio.bitrack.AssetView"
    android:id="@+id/assetView_relative_layout">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="1">

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:text="17AB05"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/assetCode" />

            <Button
                android:text="Fetch data"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/fetchUpdateButton" />

            <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart
                android:id="@+id/lineChart"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="250dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/selectionTextView"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Nothing selected" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**This is my activity main xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="it.bitrack.fabio.bitrack.AssetView"
        android:id="@+id/container">
    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**This is my app bar xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="it.bitrack.fabio.bitrack.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: you should set layout_below or layout_above for container of your activity xml between the layout with id container and appbar

Comment: @CanberkÖzçelik I tried but it did not work: <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_below="@+id/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="it.bitrack.fabio.bitrack.AssetView"
        android:id="@+id/container">
    </RelativeLayout>

Comment: using main activity @layout/content_main set the frame layout

Comment: I'm guessing you're inflating fragments into *container* so you need to give layout_below="@+id/app_bar_main" to its xml

Comment: @CanberkÖzçelik it did not work

Comment: @Akashpasupathi can you please be more specific? Thanks!

Comment: @user1060551 i post my answer below http://stackoverflow.com/a/42598636/7399521.i hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

So I'm assuming you're inflating the fragment, use the hierarchy as:

activity_main.xml
FrameLayout
--DrawerLayout
----include *app_bar_main*
----NavigationView

app_bar_main.xml:
CoordinatorLayout
--include *content_main*

content_main.xml:
RelativeLayout
--FrameLayout *(fragment_container)*

Comment: you need to place layouts as I show in order, I've also written the file names top of them

Answer (score 0):

**content_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:showIn="@layout/drawer_app_bar_dashboard"><FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/texeting_fram"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff" /></LinearLayout>
```

**your java file**

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_drawer_dashboard);//get tool bar for drawer navigation and hide main action bar
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);//initial fragment
    fragment = new Fragment_Main_Dashboard();
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.texeting_fram, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```